# How to override Bootstrap CSS on my tables

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I loaded Bootstrap and it messed up every table on my website.

What CSS can I use to override the bootstrap table css that messed up all my tables? I would like my original table styles back.

I tried some table { } entries in my CSS after the bootstrap was loaded but it did nothing.

I only want to use the Bootstrap nav bar. Is there a way to get the CSS just for the nav bar, thereby leaving my tables alone?

Comment: As I remember, Bootstrap will apply table style to its class, which named "table". So check if your tables having that class. By the way, because you want to use only navbar, why don't you copy bootstrap css navbar to your custom css?

Comment: U can customise it on the getbootstrap.com and download the customized classes from there.